# Using Couchbase with memcached protocol from Java

Tags: java, memcached, couchbase

Can someone point me to example of Java code that can work both with Memcached server and Couchbase server. If i understand correctly one can use spymemcached for communicating with both server. Does that mean i can use same code to connect(obviously using different url) get and put values to them  or there are some differences?

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason to use the memcached protocol directly?

The best practice when working with Couchbase is to use the Client SDK (many languages are supported as you can see here http://www.couchbase.com/develop , including Java) ?

The reason why it is better to use the SDK (and for the same reason you have to use Moxi) is because to be able to support the clustering from your application.

You client SDK will direct the operations to the correct cluster nodes, but also the cluster map will automatically be updated when you add new nodes (or when nodes are failing).

The Java SDK tutorial will guide you through the different steps of developing an application using Couchbase:
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-java-1.1/tutorial.html

So, can you use the Java client SDK?

Comment: Using memcached protocol is requirement from our architects.

Answer (score 0):

According to the couchbase [documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-architecture-apis-memcached-protocol.html) it support textual memcached protocol. So you can use any of the available java memcached client and reuse the same code used for memcached. Couchbase supports memcached protocol only through moxi.